# Modify JIRA Service Desk translation

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have installed Jira Service 3.2.2 and Jira Core 7.2.2.

Whenever I create a new incidence in my project, an email is sent to the user. That email is sent in Spanish and I just want to change a sentence from that email.

I've found some translations in the file

```
 \jira\plugins\installed-plugins\jira-servicedesk-application-3.2.2.jar
```

in `\i18` folder.

I've changed there the wrong sentence and restarted JIRA but the email is still the original, changes seem to not be applied.

Is it the wrong location for email templates translations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after restarting twice the JIRA server the changes were applied.

That means translations are taken from file:

```
\jira\plugins\installed-plugins\jira-servicedesk-application-3.2.2.jar
```